# mysql_connect(): Access denied for user 'adminryan'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Tags: php, mysql, sql, authentication

I'm very new to PHP and mySQL and I've been trying to create a logon via xampp with apache and mySql server. I keep on getting this error can someone explain what the error actually means? I've seen some people ask this question but the answer usually only pertains to their code especially. I'll provide my code as well. I've been watching this series of youtube tutorials if anyone is interested in what I have done http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NuiTzSdGmKM . Hope someone can help thanks! My code below:

```
<?php
$username = "yolo";
$password = "swag";
$hostname = "localhost";

$dbhandle = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password) or die("Could not connect to database");

$selected = mysql_select_db("login", $dbhandle);

$myusername = $_POST['user'];
$mypassword = $_POST['pass'];

$myusername = stripslashes($myusername);
$mypassword = stripslashes($mypassword);

$query = "SELECT * FROM logon WHERE Username='$myusername' and Password='$mypassword'";
$result = mysql_query($query);
$count = mysql_num_rows($result);

mysql_close();

if($count==1){
    echo 'It worked!';
}
```

?>

Comment: It probably means your login isn't valid / password is incorrect / account doesn't exist.

Comment: It means just what it says: That username doesn't have permission to use the database.

Comment: Concatenate the query...... $query = "SELECT * FROM logon WHERE Username='".$myusername."' and Password='".$mypassword."'";

Comment: This is **hazardously** bad code and I hope it's nowhere near the public internet. If you're new to PHP, please, use a 
[development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) rather than employing the worst practices of the 1990s. Make sure to have a guide like [PHP the Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) to answer other questions. You're not [escaping your SQL](http://bobby-tables.com/php) correctly, which means this short snippet of code is a gigantic [SQL injection hole](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Comment: @Muhammad Ali has the answer, you asking it for the user named $myusername with a password of $mypassword literally, although I prefer doing it this way " query stuff ='{$mypassword}' ".

Comment: If you're new to PHP and MySQL then you've got the chance not to learn about those deprecated mysql_* functions. It would be better to use PDO or mysqli right from the start and searching for a better and not so outdated tutorial. This [wikihow tutorial](http://www.wikihow.com/Create-a-Secure-Login-Script-in-PHP-and-MySQL) seems good at first glance.

Comment: @VMai thanks I'll check it out! It really seems that this tutorial isn't that great

Answer (score 0):

The error is about establishing the connection to a mySQL server.
(User 'adminryan' can't connect to server 'localhost' and a password was used trying to connect.
This can have several reasons, like:

- user adminryan doesn't exist.
- the provided password is wrong.
- the provided servername is wrong.
- user adminryan doesn't have the proper privileges.
- etc...

your code says:

```
$dbhandle = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password) or die("Could not connect to database");
```

so I wonder why you see the error given by you instead of "Could not connect to database".
I would expect mysql_connect would return FALSE and therefore `die("Could not connect to database")` would be executed. (And all code after `die(...)` wouldn't be executed.)

It has nothing to do with `$query = ...`
I can't, but I would vote down the comments of MuhammadAli and ArtisticPhoenix because they don't make any sense in relation to the error you provided.
And following your code this line won't be executed.

Do switch to PDO or at least mysqli though.

Answer (score 0):

For the purposes of having a possible solution for others that encounter this error and confirm the username, password and database do exist. I was coming across the same error and when restructuring my requests I was able to get the desired result.

```
$username = 'username';
$password = 'password';
$db = mysql_connect('localhost', $username, $password);
mysql_select_db("database",$db);
```

In my instance I have the full username and database being used. So it seems to depend on your cpanel account username. So for example if my domain cpanel login was mydata, then my username would be mydata_username and my database would be mydata_database.

Now I don't know if that matters or not, I haven't tested it the other way around, I have had this error a few times and this is a solution that worked for me. I don't know why it worked as I'm no expert but it did and it's worth a try for others who are experiencing the same issue.

The only difference between this code and my earlier code which is similar to this error is my use of quotes. This code is using single quotes ', the earlier code used double quotes ".